# Cannot import Realm library JAR into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, realm

I tried import Realm library JAR into Eclipse but it's so difficult. Because Realm doesn't have any JAR files for Eclipse.

I have to use JAR files from Android Studio, then import to Eclipse.

Does anyone has another solution for complete this solution?

Comment: why are you using jars? Use maven or gradle or some other dependency/build manager, otherwise it's a pain to keep track of your library versions.

Comment: @Logain, Does it's similar NuGet on Visual Studio, right?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, I can use this library in Eclipse but it's not perfect way. I finding a good solution for import it! Thanks for your suggest.

Comment: I'd suggest improving your title. The question in the title is 100% opinion-based (and is therefore off-topic), but the question in the body is acceptable.

Comment: Realm depends on the Gradle right now due to our annotation processor, gradle plugin and byte code manipulation. Just depending on our Jars will not work.

Comment: Why are you using Eclipse? The Eclipse ADT has been deprecated since 2015 june.

Comment: I building a Android application on Xamarin Visual Studio by C#. In this app, it's was intergrated a function read PDF file by the open soure MuPDF. The open source MuPDF wrote by Java, and I port it to native library by Eclipse which I can use like a reference in Visual Studio. And now, I want to use Realm in MuPDF. That's the reason I need to use Realm on Eclipse.